# c# - How do i get live output from a batch file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to get the output from the batch file but when I successfully got the output from a loop and put into a rich textbox the Form application freezes so the question how can I get a live output from a batch file (exactly a java application in console mode (Minecraft server)) without freezing the application?

Comment: Using multi-threading. Separate the threads for UI and batch output processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> output = new List<String>();

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C C:\mycommand.bat");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, evt) => output.Add(evt.Data);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Once your batch file has been executed, the list will contain its output and you can post-process it and insert it into your `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Mh... well it's just about renaming. I edited my answer.

Comment: It still not working the batch instantly closes. And I can't really put the list to a textbox whit the toArray() method.

Comment: You can use String.Join in order to create a string out of a list or an array... also, try to define a method event handler and see if the subscribed OutputDataReceived ever fires.